# How to define text-object of "between markdown code fence with syntax"?

Tags: custom-text-object

I want to create a binding for using `vim-slime` to run code between a code fence in markdown.

This worked with a simple fence, using `` i` `` as a text-object:

```
nmap <leader>s7 <Plug>SlimeMotionSendi`
```

but when adding the language to the code fence, e.g.:

````
```python
print("hello")
```
````

it obviously broke. So now I'm looking to define a text-object the would mean all the *lines* between the two triple backticks. How do I go about this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75587279/quick-way-to-select-inside-a-fenced-code-block-in-markdown-using-vim

Comment: Do you have something left open in your question? How can we help you further?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt sorry, I got extremely caught up in work and I wanted to spend a little time to understand what's going on in your answer and didn't manage to get there yet ...

Comment: No problem, I understand that :-). It was just to encourage to give feedback in case the solution weren't working for you. Take your time and feel free to comeback to us when possible for you. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define the `iq` text object:

````
vnoremap iq ?```.*$?1<CR>o/```/-1<CR>$
omap iq :normal Viq<CR>
````

Where the `v` mapping does:

- Search backward the triple quotes and move to the next line: ```` ?```.*$<CR>?1 ````
- Select the other side of the selection: `o`
- Search forward the triple quotes and move to the previous line: ```` /```/-1<CR> ````
- Go to the end of the line: `$`

And the do the following mapping:

```
nmap <leader>s7 <Plug>SlimeMotionSendiq
```

Here is another version that leave the `/` register unchanged:

````
function! VisualCodeBlock()
  call search('```', 'b')
  normal! j0v
  call search('```')
  normal! k$
endfunction

vnoremap iq :<C-u>call VisualCodeBlock()<CR>
omap iq :normal Viq<CR>
````

Remarks:

In a standard `omap` the start of the text object is the cursor position and end of the text object is the position of the cursor after the mapping has been executed.

If you need a text object that doesn't start with the cursor position you need to switch in visual mode and make the selection covering the range you want.

Usually in such case two mappings are defined such that the text object can also be used in `visual` mode.

Remark `<C-u>`:

The `<C-u>` trick is usually used when a mapping use the `Command` mode to kill the existing character in the command. If the user select some line before triggering the mapping a range will present when the mapping triggers `:`

Comment: Thanks, I finally got around to this. There are a couple of things I don't understand: a) is the only way to define on omap is to basically create a visual selection and say that this is the object? b) in the vnoremap why is there a `<C-u>`? I tested without and it worked fine. `:h` didn't help unfortunately. c) Why not just go `omap iq :normal VisualCodeBlock()<CR>`?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll extend the answer to covers these aspects :-)

Comment: `<C-u>` is necessary to prevent undesirable range injection when the user accidentally presses a number key before pressing the mapped keys. `:help <Cmd>` is a better and more modern alternative. Also, operator-pending mode mappings only work with operators. `v`, `V`, and `<C-v>` are not operators so they get their own mapping. The best practice is to a) define a visual mode mapping that covers the desired area, and then to b) define an operator-pending mode mapping that uses the visual mode mapping.

Comment: So the more modern approach would be `vnoremap iq <Cmd>call VisualCodeBlock()<CR>`?

Comment: Indeed :-) I believe I have tried that but it was not working. Maybe I should try once more :-)